# How to make popup window appear when double click on a cell in datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a data grid displaying results from a sql database. What I want to do is make it so that when I double click on a cell in the datagrid, a new window appears where that cell can be edited. I also would like to have all the info for that cell to be autogenerated into editable fields when the cell is double clicked. Any help or links to tutorials is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick event that opens the window to the cell (using datagridview would be a good idea I think).
In addition, you you just want them to edit the cell contents, you can let the control handle all that for you (enable editing, adding, deleting, etc if you want).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.onclick.aspx